# Eastward - Westward

Tags: meaning

> - I am walking toward the East.
> - I am walking Eastward.
> - I am walking toward the West.
> - I am walking Westward.

Do those 2 forms of using East and West direction really have the same meaning?

Answer (score 1):

As adverbs, [eastward](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/eastward), [westward](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/westward), northward, southward etc. as defined by [Merriam-Webster] simply mean

> towards the east/west/north/south.

So the two forms have exactly the same meaning and are interchangeable.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are they are the same.  Using the suffix **-ward** shows the general direction

> **northward
>
>   southward
>
>   inward
>
>   outward
>
>   upward
>
>   downward**

Your sentences might read

> I am walking toward**s** the East
>   I am walking toward**s** the West.

and can be shortened to

> I am walking east.
>   I am walking west.

In BrE it might be said

> I am driving to The North.

as the descriptor "The North" is used on motorway signs.

Comment: I would argue that both toward and towards are acceptable in those sentences; most sources I've seen on the difference acknowledge that it's mainly dialectal rather than semantic. Would you happen to have any sources that point to this not being the case, Peter?

Comment: "I am driving to The North" to me means "I am driving to the North of England" (or "of Scotland" if I'm already in Scotland), not just "I am driving in a northerly direction. Different.

Comment: @ColinFine Also a good point. :)

Comment: When one is driving to The North, is it not in a northerly direction? Travelling south from Scotland, there aren't any signs for "The North" as if the Lake District was in an area called "The North". I've also not seen signs that say "The South" when driving south they just say "London".

Comment: **Toward** is more AmE and **towards** is more BrE, I have adjusted my sentence but used **towards** since my example was BrE.

Comment: We say **towards** in the US too.  I'd be interested to know where you got this notion. Is it in a textbook?